# Analytical derivative of a 3D Simplex Noise field

Tags: sampling, noise

I am using Simplex Noise to generate a 3D field. The specific implementation is [FastNoise-SIMD](https://github.com/jackmott/FastNoise-SIMD).

Assume I want to have a gradient (or derivative) for a sample at Sx, Sy, Sz in that field.

Do I actually need to sample the value of the field at all neighbours of sample S?

If so, that makes it a quite expensive operation, as the 4-octave Simplex Noise function I use is already quite expensive, evaluating them for all neighbours would make it too slow for my purposes.

Is there a way to directly compute the derivative of SimplexNoise that is cheaper than getting the deltas from the neighbours?

Some Perlin noise implementations [have an analytical derivative](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/procedural-generation-virtual-worlds/perlin-noise-part-2/perlin-noise-computing-derivatives). But none of the Simplex Noise implementations that I have found support sampling the gradient along with the field value.

Have analytical derivatives been done on Simplex Noise, or is it maybe not possible for Simplex Noise?

Comment: There's no reason you couldn't do analytical derivatives with simplex noise, but maybe no one has sat down and worked it out and published it yet.

Comment: This shader uses a simplex noise algorithm with derivatives https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Ws23RD. Also if you want a FBM function that works with derivatives, scroll down a little bit and you'll find one here: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XttSz2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have published it, in several versions, and it's not difficult to do it. Simplex noise is a lot easier to differentiate because it's a sum of polynomials, rather than a nested polynomial interpolation as in classic Perlin noise.

GLSL code for 2-D and 3-D simplex noise with derivatives is here:

https://github.com/ashima/webgl-noise/tree/master/src

The 3-D version is in the file "noise3Dgrad.glsl". The 2-D version in "psrdnoise2D.glsl" additionally reimplements Perlin and Neyret's "flow noise" gradient rotations and can be made to tile over integer-sized rectangles. (Well, even-sized integer rectangles. The triangular/heaxagonal simplex grid placed some restrictions on tiling.)

I am currently working on a tiling version of 3-D simplex noise with rotating gradients as well (and analytical derivatives), and I will submit it for a more formal publication shortly, to hopefully make it more visible to implementers.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer so that it can be understood without the link? If the link expires for some reason, it isn't helpful anymore.